# c++ program and scope variables

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I compiled this c++ program with dev-c++ and give "was not declared in this scope" for all variables.

```
#include <cstdlib>                      // standard definitions
#include <iostream>                     // C++ I/O
#include <cstdio>                       // C I/O (for sprintf) 
#include <cmath>                        // standard definitions

#include <GL/glut.h>                    // GLUT
#include <GL/glu.h>                     // GLU
#include <GL/gl.h>                      // OpenGL

using namespace std;                    // make std accessible

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global data
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

GLint TIMER_DELAY = 10000;                      // timer delay (10 seconds)
GLfloat RED_RGB[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0};            // drawing colors
GLfloat BLUE_RGB[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Global variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
static bool isReversed = false;                 // draw reversed colors?

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Callbacks
//      The global variable "isReversed" describes the drawing state.
//      When false, a blue rectangle is drawn on top of red diamond.
//      When true the colors are reversed.  The "isReversed" variable is
//      complemented whenever the left mouse button is clicked or the
//      timer goes off (every 10 seconds).
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

void myReshape(int w, int h) {
    cout << "MyReshape called width=" << w << " height=" << h << endl;
    glViewport (0, 0, w, h);                    // update the viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                // update projection
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);             // map unit square to viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();                        // request redisplay
}
                                                // draw diamond and rectangle
void drawObjects(GLfloat* diamColor, GLfloat* rectColor) {
    glColor3fv(diamColor);                      // set diamond color
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);                        // draw the diamond
        glVertex2f(0.90, 0.50);
        glVertex2f(0.50, 0.90);
        glVertex2f(0.10, 0.50);
        glVertex2f(0.50, 0.10);
    glEnd();
    glColor3fv(rectColor);                      // set rectangle color
    glRectf(0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75);            // draw the rectangle
}

void myDisplay(void) {                          // display callback
    cout << "MyDisplay called" << endl;
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);           // background is gray
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               // clear the window

    if (isReversed)                             // draw the objects
        drawObjects(BLUE_RGB, RED_RGB);
    else
        drawObjects(RED_RGB, BLUE_RGB);
    glutSwapBuffers();                          // swap buffers
}

void myTimer(int id) {                          // timer callback
    cout << "Timer just went off.  Reversing colors." << endl;
    isReversed = !isReversed;                   // reverse drawing colors
    glutPostRedisplay();                        // request redraw
    glutTimerFunc(TIMER_DELAY, myTimer, 0);     // reset timer for 10 seconds
}

void myMouse(int b, int s, int x, int y) {      // mouse click callback
    if (s == GLUT_DOWN) {
        cout << "Mouse click detected at coordinates x="
             << x << " and y=" << y << endl;
        if (b == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
            isReversed = !isReversed;
            cout << "Left mouse click.  Reversing colors." << endl;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
}
                                                // keyboard callback
void myKeyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y) {
    switch (c) {                                // c is the key that is hit
        case 'q':                               // 'q' means quit
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Hit q to quit.  All other characters ignored" << endl;
            break;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Main program
//      This does all the set up for the program.  It creates the game
//      and then passes control to glut.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout <<
    "Colors swap every 10 seconds.\n"
    "Click left mouse button to swap colors.\n" <<
    "Try resizing and covering/uncovering the window.\n" <<
    "Hit q to quit." << endl;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);                      // OpenGL initializations
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);// double buffering and RGB
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);               // create a 400x400 window
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);               // ...in the upper left
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);                  // create the window

    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);                 // setup callbacks
    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);
    glutTimerFunc(TIMER_DELAY, myTimer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();                             // start it running
    return 0;                                   // ANSI C expects this
}
```

Where is the problem?

[Error] 'glutPostRedisplay' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'glutSwapBuffers' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'glutPostRedisplay' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'glutTimerFunc' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'GLUT_DOWN' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'glutPostRedisplay' was not declared in this scope

etc.

Comment: Oh my... why are you using this piece of ancient crap? Get yourself a solid IDE like [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) or [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads).

Comment: Are all the glut...() inside a namespace?

Comment: Questioning this kind of issue is not acceptable. Can't give exact answers. Only can give suggestions by guesses

Comment: Is that the beginning of your error list or the middle of it?

Comment: This code compiles and runs for me.

Comment: what builder you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GLUT docs [here](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node7.html#SECTION00025000000000000000):

> The header files for GLUT should be included in GLUT programs with the following include directive `(which you have)`:
>
> `#include <GL/glut.h>`
>
> Because a very large window system software vendor (who will remain nameless) has an apparent inability to appreciate that OpenGL's API is independent of their window system API, portable ANSI C GLUT programs should not directly include `<GL/gl.h>` or `<GL/glu.h>`. Instead, ANSI C GLUT programs should rely on `<GL/glut.h>` to include the necessary OpenGL and GLU related header files.

If you are not on windows, this may be causing an issue.

It does look like this file is not being included correctly since even the symbolic constants (e.g. for GLUT_DOWN) are not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the header files that declare these functions and variables and `include` them in this source file.

A good place to start would be this GL directory you seem to be including glut.h from, assuming it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check building without calling functions in main(). Then try one by one. I think the error is coming from one of your include files.

Are there any classes defined in those files. Check there header files are ok or not. Check for the existence of header files in specified paths.

Then check the namespaces. If you defined a class with a namespace, don't forget to use `using namespace namespace_name` or specify full qualified name for variables.

Comment: This should be a comment.